# Solving a combined system of linear and bilinear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, cryptography, gaussian-elimination

I am trying to solve a problem of breaking an amatuer cryptography.

The problem boils down to solving a combined system of linear and bilinear equations having  $50$ unknowns.

For representational purposes, the equations look similar to the following, with $x$, $y$ and $z$ being the unknowns.

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
3x + 10y + 8z + 5xy &= 1470 \\
2x + 10y + 3z + yz + xz &= 1210 \\
x + 5y + z + 3xy + 16xz &= 5540 \\
x + 3y + 8z + 12xy + 4yz  &= 5110 
\end{cases}
\end{align}

The above system has the [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bx%20%2B%203%20y%20%2B%208%20z%20%2B%2012%20x*y%20%2B%204%20y%20z%20%3D%3D%205110%20%26%26%20%20%20%202%20x%20%2B%2010%20y%20%2B%203%20z%20%2B%20x*z%20%2B%20z*y%20%3D%3D%201210%20%26%26%20%20%20%20x%20%2B%205%20y%20%2B%20z%20%2B%203%20x*y%20%2B%2016%20x*z%20%3D%3D%205540%20%26%26%20%20%20%203%20x%20%2B%2010%20y%20%2B%208%20z%20%2B%205%20x*y%20%3D%3D%201470,%20%7Bx,%20y,%20z%7D%5D&wal=header) $x=10 , y=20,  z=30$.

I want to know the method for solving these type of equations. Can gaussian elimination be applied on such a system ?

Comment: You say you have $50$ unknowns. Out of curiosity, how many equations do you have? Also, in average, how many terms are there per equation? (Since you have cross terms $x_i x_j$, simple Gaussian elimination would be difficult.)

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Accdg to this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations#Software_packages), _Maple_ has built-in functionality for such systems. However, what's the most number of equations and variables $x_i$ that Maple can handle when the system has no degree $n>1$ but includes cross terms $x_i x_j$?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII There are 40 equations. On average each have 3000 terms including cross ones.

Comment: So 50 variables, 40 equations, and 3000 terms per equation? Ouch. And an under-determined system at that. The wiki link above may point to alternative approaches.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Thanks a lot. I will check.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII And yes, it may have infinite solutions for an under determined system, as the crypto revolves around a piece of hashing algorithm which has collisions.

Comment: Hm, you can't have 3000 terms per equation. The maximum number of terms for $$\sum_{i=1}^{50}p_i x_i + \sum_{i=1,j>i}^{50}q_k x_i x_j=C$$ is $50+ 1225+1=1276.$

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Yes, you are right. From a cursory look the huge equation seems to have terms which are repeated. They would be summed, which would bring down the number of terms.

Answer (score 1):

solving equation (1) for $$z$$ we obtain
$$-5/8\,xy-3/8\,x-5/4\,y+{\frac{735}{4}}=0$$ (I)
plugging this in the second equation we obtain
$$-5/8\,{x}^{2}y-3/8\,{x}^{2}-7/2\,xy+{\frac {1477\,x}{8}}-5/8\,x{y}^{2}
-5/4\,{y}^{2}+190\,y-{\frac{2635}{4}}
=0$$ (II)
pliugging (I) in the third equation
$$-{\frac {141\,xy}{8}}-10\,{x}^{2}y-6\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {23525\,x}{8}}+{
\frac {15\,y}{4}}-{\frac{21425}{4}}=0$$ (III)
plugging (I) in the fourth equation we get
$$11/2\,xy-5/2\,x{y}^{2}-5\,{y}^{2}+728\,y-2\,x-3640=0$$ (IV)
solving (IV) for $$y$$ we obtain
$$y=-{\frac {48\,{x}^{2}-23525\,x+42850}{80\,{x}^{2}+141\,x-30}}$$ (V)
plugging this in (III) factorizing and simplifying we get
$$ \left( x-10 \right)  \left( 13120\,{x}^{4}-5741148\,{x}^{3}-54229691
\,{x}^{2}+11341510\,x+205150100 \right) 
=0$$
the rest do it by yourself.

Comment: The OP gave this system with $3$ unknowns only as an example. But his actual problem has $50$ unknowns. Since the system involves terms with $x_i$ and $x_i y_j$, the degree of the final equation would rise too fast using this approach.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Yes, I wanted an approach that can be automated such as using matrix operations. Solving a 50 variable system by hand is not possible.